# How to save matched pattern into variable using 'sed' command?

Tags: sed, text-processing

I'm trying to find a pattern using `sed` command in `file.txt` between first *char1* and *char2*  and then replace that with string. like below with `echo` mode example:

```
echo "This X is test Y. But X is not test Y." | sed 's/X[^Y]*Y/REPLACE/'
```

Also I need to save matched pattern( like `is test` {<--spaces around is important} ) in a variable.

Comment: In a shell variable? Because you can use backreferences in sed: sed `'s/X\([^Y]*\)Y/\1/'` - the `\1` will contain everything matched by `[^Y]*`.

Comment: @muru I've also tried that, correct, but I need to replace that with new word and save into a variable like "VAR"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a single invocation of sed that writes the revised line to stdout while at the same time saving the removed text in shell variable `var`:

```
$ var=$(echo "This X is test Y. But X is not test Y." | sed -nr 'h;s/[^X]*X([^Y]*)Y.*/\1/;p;x;s/X[^Y]*Y/REPLACE/;w /dev/stderr') 2>&1
This REPLACE. But X is not test Y.
```

The value of `var` is:

```
$ echo "==$var=="
== is test ==
```

Explanation:

- `h`

  This command copies the current pattern to the hold space.
- `s/[^X]*X([^Y]*)Y.*/\1/;p`

  This removes everything from the pattern space except the text between the first `X` and `Y` including any spaces.  This is then printed to stdout.  This is the output that is captured by the shell and assigned to `var`.
- `x`

  This copies the hold space back to the pattern space.  When this is done, the pattern space contains a copy of the original input line.
- `s/X[^Y]*Y/REPLACE/; w /dev/stderr`

  The substitution is made and the result is written to `stderr`.
- `2>&1`

  After the shell has captured stdout into `var`, this instructs the shell to copy stderr (which has the line with REPLACE) to stdout.

#### Aside on handling of variable `var`

The variable `var` includes the leading and trailing spaces.  If the shell were to subsequently subject `var` to word-splitting, these spaces would be removed.  To prevent that, when `var` is referenced, do so inside double-quotes, as in the example above.

Answer (score 3):

You have to accomplish that with a second sed command:

```
var=$(echo "This X is test Y. But X is not test Y." | \
tee >(sed 's/X[^Y]*Y/REPLACE/' >/dev/stderr) | \
sed -r 's/[^X]*X([^Y]*)Y.*/\1/')
```

**Exlanation:**

- You have to use `tee` to split the stream. That both `stdout` and `stderr` contain the string.
- `tee` needs a file as argument. We give `tee` a pipe where `sed` listens from and replaces the string.
- `sed` prints the string to `stderr`: The output you see in the terminal.
- The second `sed` command listens on `stdout` and extracts the needed string, that is now saved into the variable `$var` (the contect of `stdout`).

Use that to check:

```
$ echo ">$var<"
> is test <
```